# Regular expression to replace multiple occurrence of content with start and end

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like below

```
Mickey <script> 333</script>  1  <script>eee</script> 2 <script>edddde</script> 3
```

and I want it to be like below (replace all occourrence of start **script** and end **script** tag with blank)

**Mickey  1 2 3**

When I try below (it replaces whole content between first and last **script** tag

```
data = data.replace(/<script>.*<\/script>/,"")
```

I get **Mickey 3**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the non-greedy operator:

```
data = data.replace(/<script>.*?<\/script>/g, "");
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's almost what you looking for

`data.replace(/<script>(.*?)<\/script> +/g, "")`

Exact what you want can be obtained with this:

`data.replace(/<script>(.*?)<\/script>/g, "").replace(/\s+/g, " ")`

Comment: This answer actually pays most attention to the detail in the question as it ensures double spaces are replaced with one. However, the group/brackets around `(.*?)` is not necessary. So without the group it can be written as follows: `data = data.replace(/<script>.*?<\/script>/g, "").replace(/\s+/g, " ")`

Comment: @RobC, thanks, when I written I just tried some ways, so this grouping left

Answer (score 1):

You have to capture the group globally with the right sort of grouping:

```
data.replace(/<script>(.*?)<\/script>/g,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `|` operator to match either the first or second expression.
Don't forget the global operator g to match all occurrences in the string.

`data.replace(/<script>|<\/script>/g, "")`

// produces "Mickey  333  1  eee 2 edddde 3"